# How do I dynamically refresh complex divs in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to display a div a set number of times (1-5 times) based on user input. I originally tried just using javascript to store a copy of the inner html; whenever the user changed the number (1-5), I would pass the number to a javascript method which would empty the div then paste the copy of the inner html that many times (the number passed) within the div. This appears to produce plain vanilla javascript output without JQuery Mobile styles, and I haven't been able to get a refresh method to work.

```
var content = $('.someClass').html();

function setNumDivs( numDivs ){
$('.someClass').html("");
for(var i=0; i<numDivs; i++){
    $('.someClass').append(content);
}   
}
```

This is the div I am trying to repeat (1-5 times) depending on user input (a user should be able to change from 3 to 5 then back to 1, for example, and have the div repeated and displayed that number of times dynamically without a page refresh):

```
<div class="someClass">
<label for="selectionButton" class="select"></label>
<select name="selectionButton" id="selectionButton">
        <option value="default">Select a major</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<span id="someSlider" data-role="fieldcontain"> %     
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="50" min="1" max="100"/>       
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

$('#youPageId').page("destroy").page();

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to 'refresh' the div.  try using

```
.trigger('create')
```

on it. check out the docs.