# Cookie values population in an jquery-mobile page

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-mobile

I have a situation where i am trying to populate all the cookie values in the event of preview button clicked. this complete population is done in the document.ready event. The following is the code for prepop.

```
while($.cookie('date['+cnt+']')!=null)
{
   $('#date').append(""+$.cookie('date[0]'));
   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'div' + cnt);
   var detlen=$.cookie('date['+cnt+']').length;

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td>' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="txtdt" id="txtdt' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('date['+cnt+']') + '" size="12" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center" disabled="disabled">  ' +
      '<input type="text" name="txtftime" id="txtfr' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('ftime['+cnt+']') + '" size="4" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center" disabled="disabled">  ' +
      '<input type="text" name="txttotime" id="txtto' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('totime['+cnt+']') + '" size="4" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center" disabled="disabled">  ' +
      '<input type="text" name="txtac" id="txtac' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('act['+cnt+']') + '" size="15" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center" disabled="disabled">  ' +
      '<input type="text" name="txtdet" id="txtdet' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('det['+cnt+']') + '" size="'+detlen + '" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center" disabled="disabled">  ' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="txteid" id="txteid' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('ename['+cnt+']') + '">  ' +
      '<input type="hidden" name="txtsid" id="txtsid' + cnt + '" value="'+$.cookie('sname['+cnt+']') + '">  '+
      '<img src="edit.ico" alt="Edit" id="' + cnt + '" name="edit" class="toolTip" title="Edit Row" />  ' +
      '<img src="save.ico" id="' + cnt +
      '"alt="Save" name="save" class="toolTip" title="Save" />&nbsp;<img src="delete.ico" id="' + cnt +
      '"alt="Delete" name="delete" class="toolTip" title="Delete Row"/>');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
cnt++;
}

<body body style="overflow-y:hidden">
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="previewPage">
<center>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<a href="#" id="logout" data-icon="refresh">Logout</a>
<h1>Time Sheet Preview </h1>
<a href="#" id="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
</div><!-- Header -->

<div date-role="content">
<form name='frmprev' id='frmprev'>
<input type="hidden" name="txtdt" id="txtdt">
<!--<table id='TextBoxesGroup' class="demo" cellpadding="0.5" cellspacing="0.5">-->
<div id="date" data-theme="b">Date :</div>
<table id="TextBoxesGroup" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="max" id="max">
</form>
</div>
 <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
 <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><button name="sub" id="sub" >Submit</button></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><button name="cncl" id="cncl" >Cancel</button></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded with the cookie data then look and feel is of the jquery mobile is not enablesd.
Since in this I need to be listed dynamically. Hence cannot have a fixed html for this. 
Kindly do help,
Thanks in advance
Vineet M

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to do - what problems or errors are you encountering with this?

Comment: The look and feel of this outputed page is like no jquery-mobile styles are not applied can somebody can improve or suggest me other way round.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :: Yeah I have edited the question. if any doubts please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new div appended to an element with the `data-theme` attribute?
Or add the data-theme attribute to the new div.

Maybe posting your html would help further.

Comment: `<div date-role="content">` This should be 'data-role' but you could also try adding a 'data-theme' to your table element. Also <center> doesn't have any closing tag. It might just be that the HTML is too messed up for the jQM formatting ? `<body body style="overflow-y:hidden">` this doesn't look good either.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Have made all the corrections that u have sent. But still there is a failure. My issue is very similar to this issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737881/how-do-i-dynamically-refresh-complex-divs-in-jquery-mobile)
I have tried also that one but still no success

Comment: @Vineet - See the jQM docs here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html about making sure new markup is rendered - see the sections headed 'Enhancing new Markup' and 'Create vs Refresh'. remember that jQM theming is NOT the same as CSS, a jQM process applies CSS tags to apply the theme (and it needs to be told to do it).